# How to clear all form controls after submitting the form in mvc 4 razor?

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

How to clear all form controls including dropdown,radio,checkbox etc after submitting the form.I am using mvc 4 razor ,in controller  ModelState.Clear(); entered before return view().But not working.

Answer (score 0):

A view displays (or collect) information about a Model.

So, if you pass an Empty model (that is: properties in null or blank or default values) it will "clear all fields".

All you have to do is invoking again the Action that displays the view, now passing an empty model.

EDIT: You can do it in javascript, but then you have to duplicate and maintain the logic of what are default values.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?. If answers provided by stack overflow members is useful to you please upvote and accept the anser. You can also downvote if the answer is incorrect or not useful.